# get an array from a map of arrays (in firestore)

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an android app for learning to read and write in spanish.
I am trying to get a map of arrays from firestore. There, I have a document with a field called "levels" that contains the map. Like this:

levels: {
1: "papa", "mama",
2: "mapa",
3: "cama","casa"
}

[see firebase data structure here](https://ibb.co/4S246b0)

I'm getting the map this way:

```
HashMap <String, String[]> levelsMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
levelsMap = (HashMap<String, String[]>) documentSnapshot.get("levels");
```

So far, when debugging, the map has been correctly gotten and put in the levelsMap variable.

The debugger shows it like this:

[see debugger screenshot here](https://ibb.co/p35zt0B)

```
levelsMap={HashMap@13651} size:3

"1" -> {ArrayList@13656}  size = 2
  key = "1"
  value = {ArrayList@13656}  size = 2
    0 = "papa"
    1 = "mama"

"2" -> {ArrayList@13673}  size = 1
 key = "2"
 value = {ArrayList@13673}  size = 1
  0 = "mapa"

"3" -> {ArrayList@13675}  size = 1
 key = "3"
 value = {ArrayList@13675}  size = 1
  0 = "cama"
```

Then, when I try to get an array out from the levelsMap, as the debugger says it's an arrayList I try to get it with the following line

```
List<String> levels = levelsMap.get("1");
```

but android studio points an error. It says that the variable "levels" expects a List but it is getting an Array. So then I try the following (as android studio suggests)

```
String[] level1 = levelsMap.get("1");
```

This time android studio points no error, but the app crashes at that line.
the error in the console says:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
```

So, neither of those lines seem to work. Then, how can I get the level array?

Comment: If the app crashes, Android Studio should show why in Logcat.  Please post the output of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! I solved it with these lines:

```
levelsMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
levelsMap = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) documentSnapshot.get("levels");
```

then, to get a whole level array:

```
List<String> level1 = levelsmap.get("1");
```

result: level1 = {0:papa, 1:mama}

then, to get a single word:

```
String word = levelsmap.get("1").get(0);
```

result: word = papa

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> levels = (List<Map<String, Object>>) doccumentSnapshot.get("levels");
List<String> name = Arrays.asList(levels.get("1"));
```

Comment: with that line I still get an error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]

Comment: screen shot your data struct at firestore

Comment: If I put it just like you put it, it marks in red the semicolons of the number "1". And it says it is expected an int and it's getting a String.
When I take away the semicolons, it underlines the whole expression that follows to the right of the (=) sign. Telling me that it is requiered a "List <String>" and it is provided a "List <Map<String, Object>>"

Comment: then I tried replacing your second suggested line with this one:
List<String> name = (List<String>) levels.get(1);
this time, android marks no red, but when I run the app, it throws the following error on the FIRST of your suggested line. :(
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: screen shot your data struct at firestore console